# where to find GCC atmega328 startup code and linkerscript

Tags: gcc, arduino, avr

Where can I find the startup code (crt0.s or whatever it is called) for an Atmega328p (the Arduino uno chip) and the associated linker script for use with avr-gcc?

I know I can rely on the compiler to find the startup, but it seems to be provided only as object code.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go : https://github.com/vancegroup-mirrors/avr-libc/tree/master/avr-libc/crt1

and for the atmega328p:

https://github.com/vancegroup-mirrors/avr-libc/blob/23c47c61adaa52a2851efb162dd17c1db1047a93/avr-libc/crt1/iosym/atmega328p.S

**EDIT 2015/01/23**:

this is not the arduino bootloader but a *better* fork (?), maybe you can find what you need here: https://code.google.com/p/optiboot/source/browse/#hg%2Foptiboot%2Fbootloaders%2Foptiboot

Comment: Thanks! But the first link is part of a (generic) startup. Alas, it is not complete: the DSEG is copied, but the BSS is not cleared, and there is no handling of ctors and dtors (C++ global constructors and destructors). And it needs the accompanying linkerscript (which provides the labels like __data_end) to be usefull. I have no idea what the second linked file is, but certainly not a 'normal' startup.

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen just to make it sure, when you say startup code, you mean bootloader? or is it something completely different?

Comment: @WoutervanOoijen I edited my answer with a new link :)

Comment: What I am after is the code that runs before the main(), and the matching linkerscript. Hence not a bootloader. Your new link is the source of a bootloader.